# How to disable mouse cursor autohide

Tags: mouse, cursor

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.  Suddenly it my mouse cursor is only visible when I move it.  Can someone help me with a way to make it always stay visible.  It appears that somehow a mouse cursor autohide feature has inadvertently gotten activated.

I have searched the forum.  All references to the mouse cursor is either autohide, helping the users with how to hide the mouse cursor, or other unrelated issues like no cursor at all.

I'm trying to do the opposite of the other titles.  I'm trying to make my mouse stay always visible, like a default installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced same problem, but in Ubuntu 14.04. In fact, I liked that feature, but since I switched to Opera instead of Chrome, I found annoying bug making it impossible for me to scroll websites, each time cursor hid.

Anyways, my solution was simply to remove `unclutter` package.
`sudo apt-get remove unclutter`

If that doesn't help you, make sure that `unclutter` is really stopped.
`ps -A | grep unclutter`

Or simply run `sudo pkill -9 unclutter`.

Hope that helps you, but I believe you've already found the solution after 9 months :')

Comment: Thanks for the information... apparent is a default that was removed from 16.04.  This problem doesn't currently plague me an any of my computers and haven't for a while.  I did test installing unclutter and your answer, and it does resolve the issues for anyone experiencing it.  So I'm accepting your answer for the benefit of the community to know the resolution that works.  Thanks!

Comment: I had trouble finding this with "stop debian cursor disappearing" and other search terms, so I'm namedropping "cursor disappears" for searchability.